Issues HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule in Angular Standalone
I'm trying to use HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule in an Angular V 18.2.11 standalone application  and I'm encountering this error:
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_ListPokemonComponent])[_PokemonService -> _PokemonService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
My goal is to configure InMemoryDataService with forRoot.
There is mu app.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CommonModule, HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html' 
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
     
  }

}


Here is my maint.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptorsFromDi } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './app/in-memory-data.service';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  ...appConfig,
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    {
      provide: HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule,
      useFactory: () => HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false, delay: 500 }),
    },
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


How can I properly integrate the HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule into an Angular standalone application?
